# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Stacks in Chrome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

Chrome loads the site with the navbar stacked (http://www.rmsdetroit.com), but upon refresh displays it correctly on one line. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297500/bootstrap-3-rc2-custom-navbar-fixed-top-goes-on-two-line) on here, but none of the answers worked.

My Navbar Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">

  <div class="navbar-header">

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="?page=home"><img class="rms-logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="RMS Sound Studios" /></a>

    <p class="navbar-text rms-info hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a class="phone-link" href="tel:+15555555555"><span class="phone">555-555-5555</span></a><br />
    5555 Fake St<br/>
    Fakesville, MI 48009</p>

    <ul class="list-inline pull-right hidden-md hidden-lg">
      <li class="social"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/RMS-Sound-Studios/186122143923"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
      <li class="social"><a href="https://twitter.com/#!/RMSSoundStudios"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a></li>
      <li class="social"><a href="http://vimeo.com/rmssoundstudios"><img src="img/vimeo.png" alt="Vimeo" /></a></li>
      <li class="social"><a href="https://soundcloud.com/rms-sound-studios"><img src="img/soundcloud.png" alt="SoundCloud" /></a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="list-inline pull-left hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="socialbox">
      <li class="social"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/RMS-Sound-Studios/186122143923"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
      <li class="social"><a href="https://twitter.com/#!/RMSSoundStudios"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a></li>
      <li class="social"><a href="http://vimeo.com/rmssoundstudios"><img src="img/vimeo.png" alt="Vimeo" /></a></li>
      <li class="social"><a href="https://soundcloud.com/rms-sound-studios"><img src="img/soundcloud.png" alt="SoundCloud" /></a></li>
    </ul>

  </div><!-- navbar-header -->

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="?page=home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="?page=gear">Gear</a></li>
          <li><a href="?page=studios">Studios</a></li>
          <li><a href="?page=photos">Photos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li><!-- .dropdown -->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Work <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="?page=post">Post</a></li>
          <li><a href="?page=music">Music</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="?page=contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://clientftp.rmsdetroit.com">FTP</a></li>
      <li><a href="?page=blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a id="mno-a" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/mustard-and-onions/id703720255?mt=2" target="_blank"><img class="img-rounded mno-play" src="img/podcast-icon.gif" /></a></li>
    </ul>

  </div><!-- collapse navbar-collapse-->

</nav>
```

Comment: Off topic: `navbar` is not a valid ARIA role, and `src` isn't a valid property of an anchor. Consider validating your HTML. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: D'oh, you're correct, thanks! However, with all validation errors fixed, the problem still persists. Will edit the post above to reflect changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the technical reasoning behind it, but I was having this same issue (exclusively with Chrome) and resolved the issue by changing the tag containing the `navbar-brand` class from an `<a>` to a `<div>`. I looked through the Bootstrap CSS and didn't see anything that required the `navbar-brand` class to be associated with an anchor, so I see no reason why it can't be changed. You should be able to fix your issue and achieve the desired effect by embedding a link inside of the `<div>` like this:

```
<div class="navbar-brand"><a href="?page=home"><img class="rms-logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="RMS Sound Studios" /></a></div>
```